# Newest build of Chromium OS won't boot

Tags: linux, google-chrome-os

I haven't found anything useful related to this question but I bet many people having fun with the Chromium OS get this problem.

### Problem:

All builds from chromium.arnoldthebat.co.uk don't boot properly, **while builds from Hexxeh works on my old x64 laptop(Build 4028: built 20th April 2013 )**.

### Steps to reproduce my problem:

Download any build from Arnold and use Win32DiskImager to try to boot on Lenovo 14002 running Intel Pentium Dual-Core T2390 ( 1.86GHz / 533MHz / 1MB L2 Cache)

### What I see:

1. Booting into USB, a glimpse of terminal text: "EXT4-fs (sda4): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities"
2. See Chromium logo swoosh with white background
3. Wait a few seconds and the laptop reboots and cycles again

Please, can someone familiar with Chromium help me? Perhaps if my laptop is too old and Chromium had a feature change, then what's the latest version that can work for me?

---

### EDIT:

I tried Hexxeh's Swift project's build(inactive now sadly :() with Chromium 34 x86 and it worked, I would like to know what's the difference between the 2 developers' builds and why only Hexxeh's worked.

Comment: I would boot another linux livd cd and delete all partitions on the laptop.

Comment: I suggest you wait for the stable version.

Comment: @TechLife I doubt that there will be any Chromium stable version since it's a developer build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a long time ago, but I managed to use Chromium OS via installing CloudReady OS, which builds upon Chromium. It ran perfectly on that old laptop of mine.

It could do system update, which the other unofficial builds I've tried cannot.

https://www.neverware.com/freedownload